# Project generated with Spritebuilder 1.4.7 does not build

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, spritebuilder, apportable

I just downloaded the latest, at this time, Xcode 6.1 then Spritebuilder 1.4.7 and the free version of the android plugin SBAndroid-Starter-a436a938.zip. I installed all these and generated an project and tried to run it on my Nexus 6 as well as an older lg l90 running 4.4.something. In both cases I get the below result. I have re-installed a few times and also tried creating both swift (I know its not supported with android but I still tried it) and objective-c projects but have the same results each time when I click the play button. Any ideas?

This is the output from Xcode:

```
Preparing to run org.cocos2d.Untitled on device ZX1G222QJL
3113 KB/s (18312105 bytes in 5.742s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Untitled Android-debug.apk
Success

OOPS cannot just_attach because process not found
1938 KB/s (13588 bytes in 0.006s)
creating temp file for environment /tmp/tmpxBQVLA
33 KB/s (121 bytes in 0.003s)
am start -e EARLY_LIFECYCLE_DEBUG 1 -e WAIT_FOR_ATTACH 1 -e DEBUGGER_PATH /data/data/org.cocos2d.Untitled/lib/gdbserver -e DEBUGGER_PORT 5039 -n org.cocos2d.Untitled/com.apportable.GLActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=org.cocos2d.Untitled/com.apportable.GLActivity (has extras) }
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-https://github.com/apportable/gdb Feb 20 2014 18:49:38
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0 --target=arm-elf-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Loaded library /system/bin/linker
Loaded library libc.so
Loaded library libm.so
Loaded library libstdc++.so
Loaded library liblog.so
Loaded library libsigchain.so
Loaded library libcutils.so
Loaded library libstlport.so
Loaded library libgccdemangle.so
Loaded library libunwind.so
Loaded library libunwind-ptrace.so
Loaded library libbacktrace.so
Loaded library libutils.so
Loaded library libGLES_trace.so
Loaded library libEGL.so
Loaded library libETC1.so
Loaded library libGLESv1_CM.so
Loaded library libGLESv2.so
Loaded library libbinder.so
Loaded library libz.so
Loaded library libandroidfw.so
Loaded library libspeexresampler.so
Loaded library libaudioutils.so
Loaded library libcamera_metadata.so
Loaded library libsync.so
Loaded library libhardware.so
Loaded library libui.so
Loaded library libgui.so
Loaded library libcamera_client.so
Loaded library libcrypto.so
Loaded library libexpat.so
Loaded library libnetutils.so
Loaded library libwpa_client.so
Loaded library libhardware_legacy.so
Loaded library libgabi++.so
Loaded library libicuuc.so
Loaded library libicui18n.so
Loaded library libharfbuzz_ng.so
Loaded library libc++.so
Loaded library libLLVM.so
Loaded library libbcinfo.so
Loaded library libbcc.so
Loaded library libpng.so
Loaded library libft2.so
Loaded library libRS.so
Loaded library libRScpp.so
Loaded library libjpeg.so
Loaded library libskia.so
Loaded library libhwui.so
Loaded library libimg_utils.so
Loaded library libinput.so
Loaded library libinputflinger.so
Loaded library libcommon_time_client.so
Loaded library libnbaio.so
Loaded library libsonivox.so
Loaded library libstagefright_foundation.so
Loaded library libmedia.so
Loaded library libmemtrack.so
Loaded library libminikin.so
Loaded library libnativebridge.so
Loaded library libnativehelper.so
Loaded library libnetd_client.so
Loaded library libpdfium.so
Loaded library libprocessgroup.so
Loaded library libselinux.so
Loaded library libsoundtrigger.so
Loaded library libsqlite.so
Loaded library libssl.so
Loaded library libusbhost.so
Loaded library libandroid_runtime.so
Loaded library libbacktrace_libc++.so
Loaded library libart.so
Loaded library libjavacore.so
Loaded library memtrack.msm8084.so
Loaded library libexif.so
Loaded library libjhead.so
Loaded library libmtp.so
Loaded library libdrmframework.so
Loaded library libopus.so
Loaded library libpowermanager.so
Loaded library libstagefright_avc_common.so
Loaded library libstagefright_enc_common.so
Loaded library libstagefright_omx.so
Loaded library libstagefright_yuv.so
Loaded library libvorbisidec.so
Loaded library libstagefright.so
Loaded library libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
Loaded library libmedia_jni.so
Loaded library libsoundpool.so
Loaded library libaudioeffect_jni.so
Loaded library librs_jni.so
Loaded library libjavacrypto.so
Loaded library libgsl.so
Loaded library libadreno_utils.so
Loaded library libEGL_adreno.so
Loaded library libllvm-glnext.so
Loaded library libGLESv2_adreno.so
Loaded library libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
Loaded library eglSubDriverAndroid.so
Loaded library libqservice.so
Loaded library libqdutils.so
Loaded library libmemalloc.so
Loaded library libqdMetaData.so
Loaded library gralloc.msm8084.so
Loaded library libandroid.so
Loaded library libcompiler_rt.so
Loaded library libjnigraphics.so
Loaded library libwebviewchromium_loader.so
Loaded library libv.so
Loaded library libcxx.so
Loaded library libSystem.so
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 9 libraries, e.g. memtrack.msm8084.so.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
I/ActivityManager( 1948): Start proc org.cocos2d.Untitled for activity org.cocos2d.Untitled/com.apportable.GLActivity: pid=31568 uid=10092 gids={50092, 9997, 3003} abi=armeabi-v7a
I/art     (31568): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/linker  (31568): libSystem.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
D/RuntimeService(31568): searching for libs took 0.001s
D/Environment(31568): EARLY_LIFECYCLE_DEBUG=1
D/Environment(31568): WAIT_FOR_ATTACH=1
D/Environment(31568): DEBUGGER_PATH=/data/data/org.cocos2d.Untitled/lib/gdbserver
D/Environment(31568): DEBUGGER_PORT=5039
D/Environment(31568): Unable to unlink previous environment
D/LibraryLoader(31568): WAIT_FOR_ATTACH = true
D/LibraryLoader(31568): Starting debugger service
D/LibraryLoader(31568): Waiting for debugger to attach...
I/v       (31568): libv.c:41 native_debugWait: Waiting for debugger to attach...
D/DebuggerSupport(31568): Started gdbserver on port 5039 attached to pid 31568
$1 = 1
$2 = 0
I/v       (31568): libv.c:46 native_debugWait: Debugger attached.
I/v       (31568): libv.c:84 libv_init: Initializing libv (MallocGuardEdges = 0)
Loaded library libffi.so
Loaded library libCoreJava.so
Loaded library libicu.so
Loaded library libCommonCrypto.so
Loaded library libgles_apportable.so
Loaded library libxml2.so
Loaded library libCoreFoundation.so
Loaded library libcrypto_1_01j.so
Loaded library libssl_1_01j.so
Loaded library liblibsecurity.so
Loaded library libSecurity.so
Loaded library libbridge_runtime.so
Loaded library libSystemConfiguration.so
Loaded library libCFNetwork.so
Loaded library libFoundation.so
I/v       (31568): file_io.c:1779 __wrap_open: Could not open real file path /data/data/org.cocos2d.Untitled/files/Library/Preferences/org.cocos2d.Untitled.plist with error No such file or directory
Loaded library libJavaFoundation.so
Loaded library libGraphicsServices.so
Loaded library libCoreGraphics.so
Loaded library libpango.so
Loaded library libJavaKit.so
Loaded library libAndroidKit.so
E/art     (31568): Failed to register non-native method com.apportable.androidkit.block.AndroidBlockSensorEventListener.onAccuracyChanged(Landroid/hardware/Sensor;I)V as native
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String):-2
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x72bb8ec0 self=0xb5007800
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=31568 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fe1ec8
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 353391671 43421922 405 ) utm=24 stm=12 core=1 HZ=100
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe47c000-0xbe47e000 stackSize=8MB
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004c58  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 000034c1  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 002526ad  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0023618b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+162)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b1215  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+620)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b1945  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b4bcd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1324)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bd9d5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+28)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 0000a944  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::NewStringUTF(char const*)+48)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 0000a6b0  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (jni_findClass+44)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 0001ded8  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (resolve_javaClass(bridge_class_s*)+36)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 0001de0c  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (bridge_resolveJavaClass+244)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 0000f308  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (bridge_initializeClass(bridge_class_s*)+1340)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #13 pc 0000ed74  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (bridge_initialize_classes+360)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #14 pc 0000f858  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libbridge_runtime.so (__load_bridge+68)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #15 pc 0002a000  /data/app/org.cocos2d.Untitled-2/lib/arm/libAndroidKit.so (__vrt_load+836)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native method)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:428)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   - locked <0x28f4f350> (a java.lang.Runtime)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:329)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:982)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.apportable.Library.load(Library.java:148)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.apportable.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:78)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.apportable.RuntimeService.loadLibraries(RuntimeService.java:388)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.apportable.ApportableGLActivity.onCreate(ApportableGLActivity.java:17)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
F/art     (31568): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
[New Thread 31575]
[Switching to Thread 31575]
(gdb)
```

I also tried to post the output from log cat but it was too long to post here.

Comment: One thing you should try is disable MTP transfers in Xcode Preferences, see the images here: http://android.spritebuilder.com/#installation  If that does not help please post a message on the SpriteBuilder forum.

Comment: I had thought of that I but currently when I select the Apportable settings tab in Xcode causes Xcode to crash. Many people have reported that on one of the sprite builder or cocos2d forums but I can't find the link at the moment. Not on that computer. Thanks of the input though.

Comment: @startoftext Hi I am just wondering if you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi, anybody found the solution?